# IP address and the timestamp storage

Tags: php, sqlite, timestamp, ip-address

I'm trying to store IP address and a PHP session id to uniquely identify a user, to manage a user queue to control a (one) hardware device through internet with a token. When a user has the token, has permission to control the device for 2 minutes. Then I also need a timestamp, the time on which the user asked for the token.

What is the correct field type for the IP address and the timestamp in SQLite? I need an easy way to retrieve a queue from the database matching a "text" cookie session id and an IP, using timestamp to order and filter. Should I use an integer or text field? Are there functions to work with those types?

Comment: IPs are normally stored as integer. PHP has a function to convert them: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php

Comment: @hakre - that will only work for IPv4.

Comment: The session ID should be enough for identification, php handles this for you. You may want to store the ip-address for info purpose, convert it to a text string with inet_ntop().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite is weak type, but supports type affinity. At all SQLite only support a small range of "[column types](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)" ("type affinities")

```
INTEGER
REAL
NUMERIC
TEXT
BLOB
NONE
```

However, in your case you can choose: You can store a timestamp as UNIX-timestamp in `INTEGER`, or as datetime formated string in `TEXT`. See the section "1.2 Date and Time Datatype" in the document provided by the link above. There are [Date And Time Functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) to help you handle this kind of data.

The IP can be stored as `INTEGER` after converting it into one: [`ip2long()`](http://php.net/ip2long). Or you store it as `TEXT` too. I suggest to use the former one.

Update: If you choose to use `INTEGER`, you will be limited to storing IPv4 addresses only, because SQLite can only store 64 bit integers, whereas IPv6 are 128 bit. However, because `ip2long` only works with IPv4 the range is not the only issue.

Comment: This is not what he asked, obviously everybody that uses sqlite knows these types.
But he asked how to save IP address, yes you can save it as every type. But it will be slow.

Comment: Don't mix up the prolog with the actual answer: "The IP can be stored as INTEGER after converting it into one: ip2long(). Or you store it as TEXT too. I suggest to use the former one.". However, one can argue, that I missed to mentioned, that the actual use-case may be more relevant. For example, if You need the IP only to read and print it somewhere (no index), the TEXT-format is more convenient without much performance loss and without conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two sqlite C function extensions to convert strings of form `128.1.42.15` into 32-bit integers and back, the boilerplate was vaguely adapted from the sample extension: https://www.sqlite.org/src/file/ext/misc/rot13.c

ip.c

```
#include "sqlite3ext.h"
SQLITE_EXTENSION_INIT1
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#include <arpa/inet.h> /* pton, ntop */

/** ipv4 String to Integer */
static void ips2i(
  sqlite3_context *context,
  int argc,
  sqlite3_value **argv
){
  const unsigned char *zIn;
  struct in_addr addr;
  int s;

  assert( argc==1 );
  if( sqlite3_value_type(argv[0])==SQLITE_NULL ) return;
  zIn = (const unsigned char*)sqlite3_value_text(argv[0]);
  s = inet_pton(AF_INET, (const char * restrict)zIn, &addr);
  if (s <= 0) {
    /* TODO report error nicely. */
  }
  /* Need int64 otherwise overflows int32_t. There is no unsigned version apparently. */
  sqlite3_result_int64(context, ntohl(addr.s_addr));
}

/** ipv4 Integer to String */
static void ipi2s(
  sqlite3_context *context,
  int argc,
  sqlite3_value **argv
){
  struct in_addr addr;
  char zOut[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];

  assert( argc==1 );
  if( sqlite3_value_type(argv[0])==SQLITE_NULL ) return;
  addr.s_addr = ntohl(sqlite3_value_int64(argv[0]));
  inet_ntop(AF_INET, &addr, zOut, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
  /* TODO any way to avoid the strlen here? inet_ntop does not seem to return it. */
  sqlite3_result_text(context, (char*)zOut, strlen(zOut), SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
}

int sqlite3_ip_init(
  sqlite3 *db,
  char **pzErrMsg,
  const sqlite3_api_routines *pApi
){
  int rc = SQLITE_OK;
  SQLITE_EXTENSION_INIT2(pApi);
  (void)pzErrMsg;
  rc = sqlite3_create_function(db, "ips2i", 1,
                   SQLITE_UTF8|SQLITE_INNOCUOUS|SQLITE_DETERMINISTIC,
                   0, ips2i, 0, 0);
  if (rc == 0) {
    rc = sqlite3_create_function(db, "ipi2s", 1,
                    SQLITE_UTF8|SQLITE_INNOCUOUS|SQLITE_DETERMINISTIC,
                    0, ipi2s, 0, 0);
  }
  return rc;
}
```

Compile:

```
gcc -shared -fPIC -ggdb3 -O0 -pedantic-errors -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -o 'ip.so' 'ip.c'
```

Use `ips2i` from `ip.so`:

```
sqlite3 :memory: '.load ./ip' "SELECT printf('%08x', ips2i('1.128.2.10'))"
```

Output:

```
0180020a
```

where:

- 1 = 0x01
- 128 = 0x80
- 2 = 0x02
- 10 = 0x0a

Use `ipi2s` to convert back:

```
sqlite3 :memory: '.load ./ip' "SELECT ipi2s(0x0180020a)"
```

output:

```
1.128.2.10
```

IPv6 support would require:

- `AF_INET` -> `AF_INET6`
- `INET_ADDRSTRLEN` -> `INET6_ADDRSTRLEN`
- learn how to use integers larger than 64 bits, since IPv6 has 128 bits

Then we should learn how to report errors in SQLite, and merge this into SQLean: https://github.com/nalgeon/sqlean/issues/86